# cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, shared-objects, cloog

I am currently running a simulator which is mounted on a disk. When I am trying to cross compile an application, it always gives me this error:

/mnt/mipsroot/cross-tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/mips-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libcloog.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried a lot to rectify it, but in vain. Is there any way how I can get my application to cross compile?

Answer (score 1):

```
[root@Canada ~]# yum search cloog
Redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf search cloog' (see 'man yum2dnf')

    Last metadata expiration check: 0:56:47 ago on Thu Nov 10 14:11:03 2016.
    ================================= N/S Matched: cloog =================================
    cloog.i686 : The Chunky Loop Generator
    cloog.x86_64 : The Chunky Loop Generator
    cloog-devel.i686 : Development tools for the Chunky Loop Generator
    cloog-devel.x86_64 : Development tools for the Chunky Loop Generator
    [root@Canada ~]#  yum install cloog-devel
```

did you do this ?